# What is, in this sentence: アンタらみてえにご立派な目標はねえし, みたいに modifying

Tags: grammar

I stumbled upon this sentence in bold:

> 俺の言う事は素直に聞く事　お前は馬鹿でガキで道徳がない　俺はお前より先輩だし社会正義も持っているつもりだ　俺の言う事を聞いていればお前は今の生活を守れるぜ　どうだ？わかったら返事　おう頭に入れといてやらあ　安心してくれ　**アンタらみてえにご立派な目標はねえし**　ショボい夢しかねえし

The spaces just indicate that it starts a new column (it's vertical writing in the manga)

What is it that みたいに here is modifying? I'm not sure really about the whole アンタらみてえに-part, because doesn't this make an adverb (here it would mean "looks like アンタら")?

Comment: Wondering if this 〜みたいに〜ない should be translated with "like" or "unlike"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[みたい](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%BF%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84/#je-72829) has two meanings:

> 1〔類似・具体例を表す〕like
>
> 2〔推測を表す〕look; seem

The one in the example is used in the first sense.

I guess the みたい can be translated both *like* and *unlike*:

- Unlike you guys, I'm not aiming high
- I don't have a respectable objective like you

To my knowledge, English *un/like* have the same ambiguity in a negative sentence.

---

(Edit) I forgot to answer the original question: in terms of 'modifying', アンタらみてえに modifies ねえ (or ご立派な...ねえ as a whole).

Comment: This is interesting, I've never heard of "unlike" definition before. When みたいに used to mean "unlike," is it interchangeable with に対して?

Comment: @JimmyYang It is rather interchangeable with と違って. It's not impossible to use に対して (though a bit clumsy): e.g. ご立派な目標を持ったアンタらに対して、こっちにはそんなものないからな.

Comment: @JimmyYang, note too that the みたいに itself is just adverbial -- it has no negative sense. and on its own, it does n̲o̲t̲ mean "unlike". The negation in your sample sentence is from the ねえ later in the text, as sundowner notes in their "(Edit)" text.